# error when using angular js in php

Tags: php, angularjs

i want to have a editable table in my dashboard.
when i use below code

```
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success text-center" ng-show="success">';
        echo '<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="clearMessage()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> {{ message }}';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center" ng-show="error">';
        echo '<button type="button" class="close" ng-click="clearMessage()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
        echo '<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> {{ message }}';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="margin-top:10px;">';
        echo '<thead>';
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<th>Counter</th>';
            echo '<th>Class</th>';
            echo '<th>Action</th>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
        echo '<tbody>';
            echo '<tr ng-repeat="member in members" ng-include="getTemplate(member)">';
            echo '</tr>';
        echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
```

i saw this :

[image: error]

anybody knows how can i solve this???

Comment: can you share `message` output

Comment: $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

  $out = array('error' => false);
  
  $memid = $data->memid;
  $counter = $data->counter;
  $class = $data->class;

  $sql = "UPDATE checkin_class SET counter = '$counter', class = '$class' WHERE memid = '$memid'";
  $query = $conn->query($sql);

  if($query){
    $out['message'] = "Member updated Successfully";
  }
  else{
    $out['error'] = true;
    $out['message'] = "Cannot update Member";
  }

  echo json_encode($out);